# Are AWS server-side TemporaryCredentials usable for client-side S3 upload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Using a client-side version of the [AWS JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) v2.2.29 (e.g. Bower [aws-sdk-js](http://bower.io/search/?q=aws-sdk-js)) this is possible (though obviously unacceptable because it exposes the real aws credentials to the client):

```
var region = 'us-east-1',
    accessKeyId = 'AZ12341234',
    secretAccessKey = 'aBCde1FGhij2KLMnOPqr3TUvwx4YZ';

var creds = new AWS.Credentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey);

creds.get(function() {
  s3Location = new AWS.S3({
    region: my.region,
    credentials: creds
  });
  ready(); // which presents the upload form, binds events, etc..
});
```

The dream is to split the process into 2 parts, one secure server-side and the following client-side.

Part 1. Use a Nodejs server-side version of the [AWS JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) (e.g. [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk)) to do this:

```
var creds = new AWS.TemporaryCredentials(accessKeyId,  secretAccessKey);

creds.get(function() {
  var aws = {
    accessKeyId: creds.accessKeyId,
    sessionToken: creds.sessionToken,
    region: my.region,
  };
  // e.g. makes aws var available to client
  res.render('form', {
    aws: aws
  });
}
```

Part 2. Use a client-side version of the [AWS JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) (e.g. Bower [aws-sdk-js](http://bower.io/search/?q=aws-sdk-js)) to do *something like* this:

```
// e.g. aws = <from-server-side>
var creds = new AWS.Credentials(aws.accessKeyId, null, aws.sessionToken);
creds.get(function() {
  s3Location = new AWS.S3({
    credentials: creds,
    region: aws.region
  });
  ready();
});
```

The code above seems to work, until the actual chunked upload begins, which result in 403:

```
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
    The request signature we calculated does not match the 
    signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
</Message>
```

It seems the S3 SDK might be limited, and multipart uploads impossible even if such a transaction were theoretically possible.

Ought this be possible? Any ideas how?

Answer (score 0):

For your specific question, you should look at the Roles/Policies for those credentials, and ensure you are allowing multipart uploads.

Another solution is for the client to request the server to return a signed URL that allows the client to get/post the file directly to S3 (not using the AWS API but using HTTP directly.

I use FineUploader to do just that (for uploads), and they have a bunch of examples that should give you an idea (even if you don't want to use FineUploader) to how to do this:

http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html

Heruku also has an example: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node

But what you are doing (or using Cognito to do a similar thing) should work. Therefore, the problem has to be related to the role/policies associated to the temporary credentials you are creating.

Comment: Please clarify "it will be easy for anybody to get the credentials from your server" .. In the final example (not the unsafe first example), the credentials are server-side, right? I only want to send the TemporaryCredentials to the client. I haven't tried it yet, but am not under the impression that providing an IAM role while requesting Temporary Credentails will result in the provision of temp key+secret (ala Cognito, but without the user generation)

Comment: My mistake. I don't have much experience with the javascript API, and didn't realize the TemporaryCredentials was for using AWS STS. So yes, you are doing the right thing. I will update or delete my answer. Your issue is likely related to the IAM role associated to the temporary credentials.